# AS3 dynamic field on timeline won't change

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a timeline with 10 frames. Frame 6 is a keyframe.
I'm changing the text in the ENTER_FRAME event but both frame 1 and 6 can't find the TextField.

I checked over and over again to make sure the TextField is named correctly in all frames.
Could there be something I'm missing?

```
public function LoadingLevels() {
        // constructor code
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
        label_loadingLevels.text = Chief.Lang.LoadingLevels;
    }

    private function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void{
        if (label_loadingLevels)
            label_loadingLevels.text = Chief.Lang.LoadingLevels;
    }
```

Comment: show your enter_frame code, and clarify the context (where that code is placed)

Comment: I added the code to the question

Comment: That code, is it a document class?  Are you getting a 1009 error?  (when you say 'can't find the TextField').  I think I'd have to see your timeline to figure it out.  Can you post your .fla on cloud storage? (google drive/dropbox/one drive)